# Bad text definition in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

Why LibreOffice show my the text in my laptop with bad definition?

In my kubuntu the text show like that:

[image]

In Libreoffice Windows 10 like that:

[image]

Comment: I notice you have the font as `Arial`. That's a Microsoft font. Have you installed Microsoft fonts on your system? Open a terminal and run `apt policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. What is the output?

Comment: `victorsnk@victorsnk-HP:~$ apt policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer
ttf-mscorefonts-installer:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  3.4+nmu1ubuntu2
  Tabla de versión:
     3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
victorsnk@victorsnk-HP:~$ ^C`

Comment: apt policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer
ttf-mscorefonts-installer:
  Instalados: 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2
  Candidato:  3.4+nmu1ubuntu2
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status